# Equivalent Razor Syntax of Following Statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let's say I have following ASP.NET Web Form engine code, how can I express it in Razor engine?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
</script>
```

Thanks
Hardy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
</script>
```

This is exactly the same as your example (note the `Html.Raw`).

If you want the output (html)encoded or your code returns an IHtmlString :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
</script>
```

You do want to use `@( ... )` syntax, because using `@new JavaScriptSerializer(..)` will let the Razor parser stop at the first space (after new).

The syntax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @{ new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model); }; @* <== wrong *@
</script>
```

does not work because it will call `new JavaScriptSerializer`, but discard the output.